# unable to view contentversion file as public site user

Tags: force.com-sites, contentversion

I'm utilizing the following URL to load an image stored as a `ContentVersion` file in an `IMG` tag. It loads correctly in SF but not on the force.com public site:

`/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=06815000002QhYPAA0`

I've tried loading the full URL path in the browser as well `https://SITENAME.secure.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=06815000002QhYPAA0`

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: 
I created the following sample VF page to exclude any other possibilities, the image loads correctly in SF, but when I try at the site URL it fails `https://SITENAME.secure.force.com/apex/testcontent`. Seems like its accessible but not rendering for some reason.

VF PAGE

```
<<apex:page controller="ctl_testContent" >
  <!-- attempt 1 -->
  <img src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=06815000002QhYPAA0"/>

 <!-- test accessible -->
 {!cv.id}<br/>
 {!cv.versionData}
 </apex:page>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public class Ctl_Testcontent {

public ContentVersion cv {get;set;}

public ctl_testContent() {
    cv = [SELECT Id,VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE id='06815000002QhYPAA0'];
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[broken image]
06815000002QhYPAA0
core.filemanager.FileBlobValue@4bec7a37
```

UPDATE 2:
As an update to this I noticed documents are very easy to make public via `/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id={DOCUMENT_ID}&oid={ORG_ID}`. It'd be nice if there was something similar for SF Files. At this point I may have to clone SF Files to be Documents simply for this functionality. I have gotten SF Files to render in public sites but its a headache of creating a group, adding the public sites user, creating a library, adding a file to the library etc...not going to work for my use case where its automated.

Comment: Is the file accessible by the guest user? If it's in content, you can add the guest user to a public group and then share that file with the group.

Comment: @RyanGuest the file is set to viewable for all users in company and any users with link. We're not using content, just files if that makes sense. Is sharing via group the only option to make it accessible to render? The page has the correct contentversion ID so its getting the record, just won't render it.

Comment: Does your site have a path prefix?

i.e. is the home page:
https://SITENAME.secure.force.com/
or
https://SITENAME.secure.force.com/mysite/

Comment: @RyanGuest it does not

Comment: Have you tried `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/servlet.shepherd/version/download/06815000002QhYPAA0`

Comment: @Mahmood I just tried this `<a href="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0681‌​5000002QhYPAA0">asdf</a>` and got `top.location='https://testprod.secure.force.com/ex/errorduringprocessing.jsp'` when clicking the link

Comment: Reading [Make ContentVersion downloadable/accessible via Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099sOIAQ) shows a prefix on the URL for a public site.

Comment: @DanielBallinger hm, are you referring to `/abtest` in the answer? Our site doesn't have a subpath defined in `Default Web Address` on the site which is what I believe that is. It just lives at the root dir of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this now too and after ....

1. adding the guest user to a public group
2. creating a public library and then adding the file to that library

If I use

```
<img style="max-width: 100%;" src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId={!ContentVersionId}"/>
```

it doesn't work but if I use

```
<img style="max-width: 100%;" src="https://XXXX--YYYY--c.INSTANCE.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId={!ContentVersionId}"/>
```

then it works.

Compare your /apex version of the visualforce (right click on the image and open link) with the site.com URL and you will see there's a small difference.